# How to iterate a condition in a while loop? Beanshell

Tags: java, while-loop, iteration, beanshell

Edited from my original post because I found a work around.

I'm trying to use a while loop to check if inputs exist. I have inputs that can vary in size, meaning I can have one input in a case or multiple in another. I'm using a while loop to execute many lines of code if the input(s) are present. The issue is that I know that I'll have at least one input in a case but in another case I may have 5,6,7, etc.

For example if I have:

```
input0="taco";
input1="water";
input2="sand";
```

With the example above in mind how do I iterate the condition of the while loop to make sure input0, input1, and input2 get executed?

In this example all of the commands within the while loop would be executed as long as input0,1,2 exist and are defined. My hope is that the integer q will scale with each input and the code within the while loop executes based on the current input.

When the loop reaches input3 I'd like it to exit the loop because that input does not exist.

I currently have the following:

```
int q=0;
String inputV =input(q);

while(inputV.contains("~")){ //first iteration takes "taco"

    //This is where my long lines of code that need to be executed are
    // I'm hoping that q will populate with 0,1,2 as the loop goes on and take "taco" "water" "sand" respectively

    q++;
    inputV=input(q); 
    //The next iteration will be input(1) = input1 which is "water"
    }
```

New edit given the comment from Roger. The execution is having trouble getting through the if(f.equals(field)) statement. It passes through the for loop but can't process the if statement.

```
String input(int q) {
    String field = "input" + q;
    
    for (String f: global.variables) {
     if (f.equals(field)) {
       return (String) this.namespace.getVariable(field);
       }
     }
     return null;
   }
   
   int q=0;
   String inputV = input(q);
   while(inputV != null) {
       print(q + " " + inputV);
       print("The input parameter is not null");
       print("The input value is " + inputV);   
      // long lines of code executed within the while loop
      q++;
      inputV=input(q); }
```

Comment: You should not have to define the namespace. It should be available I the context. See http://www.beanshell.org/manual/specialvarsvalues.html#Special_Variables_and_Values . How do you run BeanShell? In a web page, locally, in some other application?

Comment: I'm using a UML modeling application to run Beanshell. After looking at the link it seems as though nothing else should be defined because everything else is a part of a reference. "this.variables" , "this.namespace", and "global" are all predefined references in beanshell. Am I understanding this correctly? @Roger Lindsjö

Comment: Yes, they should be part of the predefined context and "just available".

Comment: Any ideas as to why execution can't process the if statement? It handles the for loop because I placed a print within the for loop and it successfully returned the string. Thanks for your help so far by the way! @Roger Lindsjö

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried printing both `f` and `field` before the `if`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the defined variables in `this.variables`, `global.variables` or via the `namespace.getVariableNames()`. So with a helper method it is possible. In the example below I assumed they are defined in the global space.

```
input0="taco";
input1="water";
input2="sand";

String input(int q) {  
  String field = "input" + q;
  for (String f: global.variables) {
    if (f.equals(field)) {
      return (String) this.namespace.getVariable(field);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

int q=0;
String inputV = input(q);
while(inputV != null) {
    System.out.println(q + " " + inputV);
    q++;
    inputV=input(q); 
}
```

But, isn't there a better way for you to define the values such as array or list?

Comment: So I've narrowed the issue down. I'm not able to execute if(f.equals(field)) because of global.variables. Same thing goes for the return using this.namespace.getVariable(field) and since these two aren't understood the while loop is not executed. What are these? Do global.variables and this.namespace.getVariables need to be defined as strings?? Patience is appreciated this is my first experience with beanshell/java, thank you. @Roger Lindsjö